# UIImageView tap gesture not working on image tap

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage, uigesturerecognizer

I have assigned a image in table footer, the tap is recognized just on few pixels outside the image's top left, BUT not on the image taping. Can you pls correct me where I'm doing the mistake. I wanted the call a method when the image is tapped.

Here is the code.

```
-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{    

if(section==1)
{
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    timgview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(285, 5, 20, 20)];
    timgview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openURL:)];
    tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tapped.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [timgview addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
    timgview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    [headerView addSubview:timgview];

    return headerView;
 }
}

-(void)openURL:(id) sender
{
    NSLog(@"Opening URL");
}
```

Comment: it worked fine after increasing the footer height of the section.